# fatal error: *.h: No such file or directory. While running docker build command to create image for python project

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes, dockerfile

There is a python project in which I have dependencies defined with the help of "requirement.txt" file. One of the dependencies is gmpy2. When I am running `docker build -t myimage .` command it is giving me following error at the step when setup.py install is getting executed.

```
In file included from src/gmpy2.c:426:0:
src/gmpy.h:252:20: fatal error: mpfr.h: No such file or directory
include "mpfr.h"
```

similarly other two errors are:

```
In file included from appscript_3x/ext/ae.c:14:0:
appscript_3x/ext/ae.h:26:27: fatal error: Carbon/Carbon.h: No such file    
or directory
#include <Carbon/Carbon.h>

In file included from src/buffer.cpp:12:0:
src/pyodbc.h:56:17: fatal error: sql.h: No such file or directory
#include <sql.h>
```

Now question is how i can define or install these internal dependencies required for successful build of image. As per my understanding gmpy2 is written in C and depends on three other C libraries: GMP, MPFR, and MPC and it is unable to find this.

Following is my docker-file:

```
FROM python:3

COPY . .

RUN pip install -r requirement.txt

CMD [ "python", "./mike/main.py" ]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install this `apt install libgmp-dev libmpfr-dev libmpc-dev` extra dependency and then `RUN pip install -r requirement.txt`
i think it will work and you will be able to install all the dependency and build docker image.

```
FROM python:3

COPY . .

RUN apt-get update -qq && \
apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
libmpc-dev \
libgmp-dev \
libmpfr-dev

RUN pip install -r requirement.txt

CMD [ "python", "./mike/main.py" ]
```

if apt not run you can use Linux as base image.

Comment: Error: Package 'libmpfr-dev' has no installation candidate
Error: Package 'libmpc-dev' has no installation candidate
The command '/bin/sh -c apt install libgmp-dev libmpfr-dev libmpc-dev' returned a non-zero code: 100

Comment: Terminal is exiting command prompt see the output:
.........
libgmp-dev is already the newest version (2:6.1.2+dfsg-1).
Suggested packages:
  libmpfr-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libmpc-dev libmpfr-dev
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 256 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1324 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort.
The command '/bin/sh -c apt install libgmp-dev libmpfr-dev libmpc-dev' returned a non-zero code: 1

Comment: After update output is - 

The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libmpc-dev libgmp-dev libmpfr-dev RUN pip install -r requirement.txt' returned a non-zero code: 100

Comment: remove last '\' from- libmpfr-dev \ in your updated answer and now its installing.

Comment: Okay great that cool is it working build done otherwise can you please requirement.txt file

Comment: Build is running currently mean while can you please tell me from where we can find the syntax knowledge of writing Docker-file is their any standard source ?? as i have few more dependencies to be resolved like mentioned in my original query.

Comment: Great ! it resolved one of the dependency Thanks a lot !! (Y)

Comment: There is nothing like proper source once you can know the dependency of the application you can choose the base image from docker-hub and good to go. But sometimes only it happens it's necessary to download other dependencies before installing main.

Comment: @VenuGopalTewari Thankyou always there to help.

Comment: @VenuGopalTewari If it solved your issue you can also mark this answer as `solved` it's how this stackoverflow works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to modify your Dockerfile to install the additional C libraries using `apt-get install`. (The default Python 3 image is based on a Debian image).

```
sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev
sudo apt-get install libmpfr-dev
```

It [looks like you can install](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Install) the dependencies for `pyodbc` using

```
sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev
```

However, I'm really unsure about the requirement for `Carbon.h` as that's an OS X specific header file. You may have an OS X specific dependency in your requirements file that won't work on a Linux based image.

Comment: Error: Package 'libgmp3-dev' has no installation candidate

Comment: @VenuGopalTewari

Can you please run `lsb_release -a` to identify your OS distribution and version? It's a good place to start when dealing with package issues.